# Invalid Key hash with Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, keytool

I'm trying to use Facebook Android SDK to develop a simple app with the Facebook Login Button.
But i'm having trouble with Key Hashes. I've created both a debug key and a release key:

Debug key:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Release key:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

And then i copied this key hashes in the Facebook Developers page.
When i export the apk and copy it into the device it works well, but when i try to install the app from Eclipse (run as/debug as Android Application) it doesn't work. It seems that the app is using a different key hash from the one i've created with keytool.
Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: is it ask you password ?

Comment: You Can Check your Hash key like this
1.Check if your system as 32 bit Operating System you can use OpenSSL 32 bti from [here](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip) and generate key then compare to programmatic generated hash key if both same it works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to get the HashKey from here

```
public static void showHashKey(Context context) {
            try {
                PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                        "com.example.tryitonjewelry", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); //Your            package name here
                for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    Log.i("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                    }
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is fantastic. 
Couldn't work out why the hash we entered was still invalid. Some of the characters were too ambiguous. This allowed for a sweet copy and paste :)

Comment: I recommend using "context.getPackageName()" to get the package name and make your method more reusable. Also note that if you wrap the Base64.encodeToString in quotes then there are some stray characters that may be desirable to strip.

Comment: I had the same problem with my keytool signature output not matching what FB expected. Turns out I was impulsively entering my sudo password for the keystore. As soon as I entered no password for the debug.keystore, the keytool output matched what FB expected!

Comment: Thanks - I don't know why the keytool method doesn't work but your method solved my issue. Can confirm its working with Android Studios 1.3 preview with Facebook SDK 4.

Answer (score 2):

```
 try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your pakage name here", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.e("KeyHash:", "key is: "+Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));

                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

            Log.e("error","error name not found");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

            Log.e("error","error no algorithm");

        }**strong text**
```

By using this one u can get ur key hash and then use this one in facebook devloper site.

Comment: If you are giving the same answer which has been posted and then try being supportive to the answer posted rather than posting it again.

Comment: its ok.actually i didnt sean your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
         PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your package name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
         for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", "KeyHash:  " + Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
         }
      }
      catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

      }
      catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

      }
```