# Invalid key hash! the key hash does not match any stored key hashes facebook android

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

After running 4-5 times this app i got this error before below error it was working fine. 
Error:Invalid key hash! the key hash does not match any stored key hashes facebook android
Hashkey is not generating in logcat. 
link: [Invalid Key hash with Facebook Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953263/invalid-key-hash-with-facebook-android-sdk)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {



    public static void showHashKey(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.virgosys.sharedynamic", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); //Your            package name here
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.i("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
    }

    private LoginButton loginBtn;
    private Button postImageBtn;
    private Button updateStatusBtn;

    private TextView userName;

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays
            .asList("publish_actions");

    private static String message = "Sample status posted from android app";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, statusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        loginBtn.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                if (user != null) {
                    userName.setText("Hello, " + user.getName());
                } else {
                    userName.setText("You are not logged");
                }
            }
        });

        postImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        postImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                postImage();
            }
        });

        updateStatusBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_status);
        updateStatusBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        buttonsEnabled(false);
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            if (state.isOpened()) {
                buttonsEnabled(true);
                Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session opened");
            } else if (state.isClosed()) {
                buttonsEnabled(false);
                Log.d("FacebookSampleActivity", "Facebook session closed");
            }
        }
    };

    public void buttonsEnabled(boolean isEnabled) {
        postImageBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
        updateStatusBtn.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    }

    public void postImage() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Request uploadRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), img, new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Photo uploaded successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            uploadRequest.executeAsync();
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    public void postStatusMessage() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), message,
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            if (response.getError() == null)
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                        "Status updated successfully",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    public boolean checkPermissions() {
        Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (s != null) {
            return s.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
        } else
            return false;
    }

    public void requestPermissions() {
        Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (s != null)
            s.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                    this, PERMISSIONS));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
        buttonsEnabled(Session.getActiveSession().isOpened());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(savedState);
    }

}
```

Comment: That clearly indicates that your keyhash is not valid, have you created your KeyHash using debug.keystore? Because when you running your application in debug mode, you must need to create keyhash using debug.keystore.

Comment: Development keyhash: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64 I have generated from this @ pratt

Comment: @PoonamKukreti are you using Windows or Linux or mac?

Comment: You have to create a signed keystore which will give you a signed MD5 and SHA, you have to put this keyHash in your facebook app(on Facebook Developer console), Then it will work, do not use debug.keystore for facebook twitter integration, make a separate signed keyStore check [This](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)!

Comment: @BhavikMehta Ya bhavik, you are right, but when you application is under development, when you need to run each and everytime, you need debug.keystore's keyhash, and facebook allows multiple keyhash at a time.

Comment: @pratt Agree with you!, but its better to verify facebook like thing by always deploying a signed apk in a real device

Comment: @PoonamKukreti Check my edited answer below dear.

Comment: @BhavikMehta Ya right, but signed apk will come in picture untill and unless you will complete your development perfectly, otherwise why should developer create signed apk, if he or she is not developed things fully.

Comment: @pratt, ow! not agree with you in this case, there are many scenarios when you have to create a signed apk every time and run it even you are still under development, i think you haven't gone through IAB process

Comment: @PoonamKukreti, Leave all the things, Check [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/)! and verify where you are doing it wrong, Facebook Integration is explained in a very simpler way here

Comment: @ Bhavik Mehta How to post log cat here it is too long

Comment: @PoonamKukreti No need of logcat, error is crystal clear here, then why you want to ask for Logcat @BhavikMehta?

Comment: @pratt how can you recognize an error is crystal clear? from the question of OP? Facebook Integration involves various steps in it and you know it, to watch over it, i asked for the logcat

Comment: @ Bhavik Mehta I have done this also but same error is coming and i am working on it from 2 weeks.I have gone through stack overflow for this but not getting success.And today i have done login in facebook through my different app generated different keyhash that is working fine .

Comment: @ Bhavik Mehta I will mail you logcat provide me your mail id.

Comment: @PoonamKukreti, bhavikmehta5491@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by copying the same key hash which was coming as the exception then I add it to Facebook .I have done this before also but at that time  it didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

You need to create keyhash using below command on command line tool, if you using Linux Operating System.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

For Windows:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

It will ask for you password, so just enter "android" and it will return you keyhash for debug.keystore. Then just copy it and paste it on your Facebook developer console. When you going to release your application, means when you creating build for your application as a signed application, at that time just use your application's keystore and use same command but just replace debug.keystore with your keystore name, alias and password. Most important, Facebook allows multiple keyhash, so do not remove debug keyhash when you enters live one. Let both of them are there always.

Comment: @PoonamKukreti When you creating keyhash, is it asking for password ? Or its creating keyhash directly?

Comment: Yes.password : android @pratt

Comment: @PoonamKukreti hmm okay, can we coordinate on gtalk? If you dont mind?

Comment: @PoonamKukreti And if it is asking password, then it must need to work, just wait for sometime and then try again, Facebook sometimes takes some time to reflect your keys there.

Comment: @ pratt ok give me your email id